# Django: Trying to create a user score system

Tags: python, django

So instead of making this into a new app or actually add it to the `User model` I want to just calculate this in the view. So here are two lines of code that I've added to get the number of posts a user has created and then multiplying it by 10 (the value I'm giving to adding a post) in the view and then passing it into the template. However, I am getting an error.

Not sure if I'm going about this in the best way, but heres what I have.

Code the in the view:

```
posts = UserPost.objects.filter(author=user)
posts_count = posts.len() * 10
```

The error:

```
AttributeError at /user/2/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'len'
```

I also tried with `.count` instead of `.len()`

Comment: try posts.count() if posts is not None

Comment: @SergAnuke that worked idk why I didn't try count as a function lol if you post is an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
posts = UserPost.objects.filter(author=user)
posts.count()
```